# How to highlight a mat row based on the condition of mat checkbox check and uncheck

Tags: angular-material

I need to highlight a mat-row when the mat-checkbox is checked.

[image]

Comment: Please include the code in your image in text (as formatted code) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `mat-checkbox` you can use the `(change)` event to toggle your `'highlighted'` value and set it to the current `checked` state of the checkbox:

```
  <mat-checkbox
    #checkbox
    (change)="element.highlighted = checkbox.checked"
  ></mat-checkbox>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krea9i?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html